# How to create a getter method for an abstract method that is inside an enum in Java?

Tags: java

I have an enum that contains an non-public abstract method and I can not change the visibility of this abstract method. The abstract method is implemented for every single unit inside the enum.

I am trying to access this method from another package for the purposes of unit testing, but I can not because it is not visible in the other package. Is there a way where I can create a getter method for an abstract method?

Is there a different way to do the unit test in a way that does not involve using a getter method or changing the visibility of the abstract method?

Here is an example of the code I am working with:

```
public enum random {
    A{
    someFunction() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    }
    B{
    someFunction() {
    System.out.println("B");
    }
    }
    C{
    someFunction() {
    System.out.println("C");
    }
    }

    abstract void someFunction();
};
```

Comment: showing some code you tried will be much appreciated

Comment: If you absolutely must have visibility into package private methods, put the test class in the same package hierarchy as the class under test? I.e. if the class is `com.x.app.MyEnum`, residing in `/src/main/java` set up the same `com/x/app` hierarchy in your `src/test/java` tree.  If you're trying to access a `private` or `protected` method, you should rethink your testing strategy.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, since it is a large code base and we have to have all of the tests in a certain place.

Comment: Please post an example of what you're trying to access...both the class and whatever thing(s) inside the class you want to access.

Comment: @user13834264 I second Steve's request.  Also, prepare to learn to use reflection.  _"I can't do that, since it is a large code base and we have to have all of the tests in a certain place"_ - You can put the tests anywhere, just set up the appropriate package hierarchy.  That is the accepted way to unit-test package private methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.  One way, like you suggested in your question, is to use a public method to expose your package-private method.  Here's a short example of such a program:

```java
public enum MyEnum {
    A {
        @Override
        void someFunction() {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    },
    B {
        @Override
        void someFunction() {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    },
    C {
        @Override
        void someFunction() {
            System.out.println("C");
        }
    };

    abstract void someFunction();

    public void someFunctionPublic() {
        // Here I'm just calling the package-private method from a public method:
        someFunction();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Other {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Here I call my public method:
        MyEnum.A.someFunctionPublic();
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
A
```

The other way is to use something called reflection.  You mentioned that you wanted a way to access the method without creating a getter method.  This is how you can do just that:

```java
// This is exactly how you had it, no changes:
public enum MyEnum {
    A {
        @Override
        void someFunction() {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    },
    B {
        @Override
        void someFunction() {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    },
    C {
        @Override
        void someFunction() {
            System.out.println("C");
        }
    };

    abstract void someFunction();
}
```

```java
public class Other {
    // Note the throws clauses, this is important because I call methods that throw checked exceptions:
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
        // Get a handle on the method:
        Method method = MyEnum.class.getDeclaredMethod("someFunction");

        // Set it to be accessible (since you specified it to be package-private):
        method.setAccessible(true);

        // Invoke it using the implementation in MyEnum.A:
        method.invoke(MyEnum.A);
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
A
```

Please note that reflection can get out of hand quite quickly, especially if you start renaming methods and/or changing the method headers.  Useful for testing, yes, but I would keep it out of production code.  Also, a small terminology thing, you refer to "methods" as "functions" in your question.  A method is a function that belongs to an Object, so since Java is entirely object-oriented, there are no functions in Java.